# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue React Native

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to test my React Native v0.40.0 application on my physical iPhone 6s device. I've been having a ton of issues and not sure why. When building the application, it says it succeeds but shows a fatal error 'cxxreact/JSBundleType.h' file not found under Buildtime errors and the application doesn't get installed onto my phone. Additionally, I managed to install it once a few days ago, but was having issues making api calls since the call was being made to localhost so I believe the `fetch()` calls weren't resolving correctly. I found this article https://tylermcginnis.com/test-your-react-native-app-on-your-iphone-or-ipad-c632b4beb3ed/ but the AppDelegate.m file is different now so I don't know how to make the modification that everyone is suggesting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue and found answers no where...I wish a had a better solution for you but what worked for me was running `react-native upgrade` and resetting everything :/